# How to toggle the *Python* buffer?

Tags: python, elpy

When working on python code in `elpy`, I like to have the python shell open.

Often I don't want the `*Python*` buffer to be visible, especially with several buffers with Python code or long Python files open.

I found the package [eshell-toggle](https://github.com/4DA/eshell-toggle) which is basically doing the same for `eshell` buffers what I would find useful for the `*Python*` buffer.

1. If eshell-toggle’d buffer is already visible in frame for
   current buffer then select (toggled) eshell window.
2. If current window is (toggled) eshell itself then hide it.

Is there a good way to toggle the `*Python*` buffer?

Comment: It seems relatively easy to write some functions that would do what you want. Leverage the functions `elpy-shell-switch-to-shell` and `delete-window`.

Comment: How about `(switch-to-buffer "*Python*")"`? Or `switch-to-buffer-other-window`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so familar with `elisp`, but as [aadcg](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68440/how-to-toggle-the-python-buffer#comment109395_68440) pointed out that `elpy-shell-switch-to-shell` and `delete-window` might work I gave it a try.

```lisp
(defun python-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (cond ((equal (buffer-name) "*Python*") (delete-window))
        ((get-buffer "*Python*") (elpy-shell-switch-to-shell))
        ((derived-mode-p 'python-mode) (run-python))
        (t (message "Not in python-mode."))))
```

With this function toggling the `*Python*` buffer works.

If you want to bring the `*Python*` buffer to front when sending code via any `elpy-shell-send-*` function, you need to set `(setq elpy-shell-display-buffer-after-send t)`

But as I'm not familiar with `elisp` this code can probably be improved quite a bit.

Comment: `(buffer-local-value 'major-mode (get-buffer (current-buffer)))` is just `major-mode`. Instead of comparing strings, you can compare symbols: `(eq major-mode 'python-mode)`. But in fact this should be `(derived-mode-p 'python-mode)`.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' thanks for pointing that out! That's indeed better.

Comment: @wuff nested conditionals are a bit hard to read. Consider using `cond`, instead of `if`.

Comment: @aadcg Indeed, using `cond` makes it more readable! Thanks!

Comment: I'll mark it as solved now after all your suggestions! This answer is actually more the contribution of aadcg and Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' than mine! Thanks a lot!